# Where is the global tslint.json file used by VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am trying to get tslint auto-saving in VS Code, especially for .vue files. In the documentation for the vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin it says says you can use the tslint.configFile setting:

> tslint.configFile - The configuration file that tslint should use instead of the default tslint.json. A relative file path is resolved relative to the project root.

So I could use this to point to a local project file on my pc and make sure that is configured to lint .vue files. But if there is a default global tslint.json file somewhere I would rather change that, rather than use the tslint.json file against a particular project for global vscode settings.

But I can't find it anywhere. Or am I missing something?